# custom module in Drupal 6.26

Tags: drupal

I am working in Drupal 6.26. I am developing a custom module, in which i am i want to upload file in node creation page. I want an option to upload image, like there should be file upload component and a upload button. So when admin select a file and click on submit button file has to get saved in a folder and need to save the path in database. After upload the image thumbnail should appear with remove button. When the admin clicks on remove button the image thumbnail should disappear and file upload component has to displayed with upload button. On save of the node, the image path has to map with node. This is similar to cck file upload option. Please help me to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this would be a complex form using AHAH (AJAX) behaviour to both get the thumbnail displayed and the remove button functionality.
I would recommend starting off by studying the File upload and CCK code so you can define simple form using the Form API and then adding to it some AHAH magic.

You can get a good example of a AHAH module in Drupal 6 [here](https://injustfiveminutes.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/appending-form-elements-using-ahah-asynchronous-html-and-http/)